# simple call to glViewport causes blank screen

Tags: opengl

This has no `glViewport` and draws correctly:

```
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glColor3f(1.0f, 0,0);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
{
    glVertex3f(  0.0,  1, 0.0);
    glVertex3f( -0.2, -0.3, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(  0.2, -0.3 ,0.0);

}
```

The coordinates of the vertices are all within -1 and 1, so I added a viewport which should contain them:

```
glViewport(-1,-1,2.0,2.0);

glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glColor3f(1.0f, 0,0);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
{
    glVertex3f(  0.0,  1, 0.0);
    glVertex3f( -0.2, -0.3, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(  0.2, -0.3 ,0.0);

}
```

As soon as I do this, the screen is blank. Without the viewport, visually the screen appears to be drawing in units such that the screen width and height are 2, as demonstrated by the demo triangle. I can also place something at -1,-1 and it is in the lower left corner, which is why my `glViewport` is also set that lower left coordinate. What is the obvious reason it is not displaying anything after the viewport?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems you missunderstood what `glViewport` does: It defines to which **pixel** coordinates the visible NDC range ([-1, 1]) should be mapped. If you use [-1, -1, 2, 2], then the whole image is drawn from pixel -1 to pixel 1 in the window.

If you want to specify which area of your world-coordinate system is mapped to the visible NDC range, you should use an appropriate projection matrix.

Comment: I think `glOrtho` or `glTranslatef` and `glScalef` are worth mentioning.

Comment: Thank you, as it would turn out my bug is due to a problem with my existing ortho projection using GLKit on OSX. I've opened a new question.

Comment: @lisyarus All 3 of those functions are deprecated and not available in core OpenGL. You're better off using a library like GLM.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Yes, they are deprecated. Yet, they are still supported on most implementations, and provide a really nice start for beginners. Seeing that the question author uses the fixed function pipeline already, I don't see any reason in forcing him to write a hundred lines of modern core OpenGL before he gets the clue of what is happening.